# Отступ скрола для UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

Имеется `UITableView`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо чтобы `contentOffset` начинался ниже верхнего вью, а так при скроле в низ что бы он останавливался под кастомной вью которая сверху.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы хотите называеться, contentInset.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

64 это высота вашей вьюшки.

Надеюсь помог вам)
Что бы лучше разобраться в разнице contentOff и contentInset, советую прочитать вот эту [статью](https://fizzbuzzer.com/understanding-the-contentoffset-and-contentinset-properties-of-the-uiscrollview-class/).

Comment: Супер, спасибо огромное!